# Copying a section from PDF with filled fields in Python

Tags: python, pdf, python-tesseract, pypdf, pdf2image

I will try to describe the process.

1. Fill in the fields "Textové pole60" with value "123456789"in the interactive PDF using the following code and save it:

```
from PyPDF4 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from PyPDF4.generic import BooleanObject, NameObject, IndirectObject

def set_need_appearances_writer(writer: PdfFileWriter):
    try:
        catalog = writer._root_object
        # get the AcroForm tree
        if "/AcroForm" not in catalog:
            writer._root_object.update({
                NameObject("/AcroForm"): IndirectObject(len(writer._objects), 0, writer)})

        need_appearances = NameObject("/NeedAppearances")
        writer._root_object["/AcroForm"][need_appearances] = BooleanObject(True)
        return writer

    except Exception as e:
        print('set_need_appearances_writer() catch : ', repr(e))
        return writer

infile = "DOTAZNIK_ADULT.pdf"
outfile = "DOTAZNIK_ADULT_VYPLNENY.pdf"

inputStream = open(infile, "rb")
pdf = PdfFileReader(inputStream, strict=False)
if "/AcroForm" in pdf.trailer["/Root"]:
    pdf.trailer["/Root"]["/AcroForm"].update(
        {NameObject("/NeedAppearances"): BooleanObject(True)})

pdf2 = PdfFileWriter()
set_need_appearances_writer(pdf2)
if "/AcroForm" in pdf2._root_object:
    pdf2._root_object["/AcroForm"].update(
        {NameObject("/NeedAppearances"): BooleanObject(True)})

field_dictionary = {"Textové pole60": "123456789"}

pdf2.addPage(pdf.getPage(0))
pdf2.updatePageFormFieldValues(pdf2.getPage(0), field_dictionary)

outputStream = open(outfile, "wb")
pdf2.write(outputStream)
inputStream.close()
outputStream.close()
```

2. Then, when I open the PDF in the adobe reader, the value is filled in there:
   [Filled field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzczg.png)
3. Then I want to convert the page from PDF to an image, but I do not have the value filled in here [After run script and show pil_im in spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfkVw.png) with this code:

```
import pdf2image import pytesseract from pytesseract import Output

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

pdf_path = "DOTAZNIK_ADULT_VYPLNENY.pdf"

images = pdf2image.convert_from_path(pdf_path, poppler_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\Poppler\\bin')

pil_im = images[0]
```

Please, help me! :)
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to create Minimal, Reproducible Examples in your questions. For instance, would it be possible for you to include the pdf you're working on? :)

Comment: Thank you for the welcome :). Unfortunately, I can't attach a pdf - this is an internal document :(